# Как из CF7 отправить в ACF несколько значений чекбокс?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form7

Делаю форму на contact-form7 на фронте для добавлении записи в wordpress. Пришел к тупику в одном моменте, как мне отправить данные чекбокса в запись?
в functions.php

```
function created_post_in_cf7( $contact_form ) {

    $title   = $_POST['company-title'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-title'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company-title'] ) : '';
    $product = $_POST['company-product'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-product'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['company-product'] ) : '';
    $video   = $_POST['company-video'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-video'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company-video'] ) : '';
    $stoimost = $_POST['company-stoimost'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-stoimost'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['company-stoimost'] ) : '';
    $budjet   = $_POST['company-budjet'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-budjet'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company-budjet'] ) : '';
    $datastart = $_POST['company-data-start'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-data-start'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['company-data-start'] ) : '';
    $dataend   = $_POST['company-data-end'] && ! empty( $_POST['company-data-end'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company-data-end'] ) : '';
    $tematiki_kanalov   = stripslashes($_POST['tematiki_kanalov']);

    $ars = [
        'post_type'    => 'company',
        'post_title'   => $title,
        'post_status'  => 'pending',
        'meta_input'   => [
            'product' => $product,
            'video' => $video,
            'tematiki_kanalov' => '$tematiki_kanalov',
            'stoimost' => $stoimost,
            'bjudzhet' => $budjet ,
            'data_nachala' => $datastart,
            'data_konca' => $dataend,
            'status' => 'obrabotka', ],
    ];

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $ars );

    $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail');

    if ( false !== $post_id ) {
        $mail['subject'] = $mail['subject'] .' Создана запись №'. $post_id;
    }

    $contact_form->set_properties(['mail' => $mail ]);
}


$tematiki_kanalov = stripslashes($_POST['tematiki_kanalov']);
```

это и есть чекбокс делал и так

```
$tematiki_kanalov = $_POST['tematiki_kanalov']
```

и так

```
 $tematiki_kanalov = $_POST['tematiki_kanalov '] && ! empty( $_POST['tematiki_kanalov '] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['tematiki_kanalov '] ) : '';
```

на фронте

```
 <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="tematiki_kanalov[]" class="chack" id="tematiki_kanalov-2"   value="blog"><span class="custom-checkbox"></span><span class="checkbox-text">Блоги</span>  </span></label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="tematiki_kanalov[]" class="chack" id="tematiki_kanalov-3"   value="family"><span class="custom-checkbox"></span><span class="checkbox-text">Дети и семья </span></span></label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="tematiki_kanalov[]" class="chack" id="tematiki_kanalov-4"   value="health"><span class="custom-checkbox"></span><span class="checkbox-text">Здоровье</span>   </span></label>
                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="tematiki_kanalov[]" class="chack" id="tematiki_kanalov-5"   value="games"><span class="custom-checkbox"></span><span class="checkbox-text">Игры</span> </span></label>
```